# Alternatives to Issuu? HTML5 / Tablet Friendly

Tags: android, ipad, html

I need to find a new service like Issuu to manage some digital publications, because obviously not all devices support Flash.

Do any of you know any alternatives to Issuu that will still serve a flash version (not required but would be ideal) and a HTML5 web app friendly version that is cross platform compatible for desktops + tablets?

I look forward to your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue.com can serve html5 versions. Not everything is set up that way yet (They have quite a backlog) but I believe you can set up an html5 version when you upload a magazine.

They also have an iPad app already.